# Scraping text from a website and the text I want does not appear in the source

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab the name and price of each of the products on the website https://store.com/shop.

When I manually view the website I can see the HTML code for each product but when I try to view it on beautiful soup using python I don't see it.

I think the problem is that the website displays the product on some sort of widget so it is not visible on the source code, but I am not sure.

```
my_url = 'https://store.com/shop'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15"}

##opens connection, grabbing page
source = requests.get(my_url, headers=headers)
html = source.content
soup =  BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print (soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Seems like the target site is [offline](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/roeblingliquors.com) as of this writing.

Comment: "*when I try to view it on beautiful soup using python I don't see it*" Ok, what *do* you see? [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The products are loaded dynamically via sending a `GET` request to:

```
https://roeblingliquors.com/api/v1/products/search.json?additional_properties%5Btype%5D%5B%5D=Spirits&new_style=true&merchant_id=5b19b7150fb4f72d6831344b&limit=20&skip=0&api_key=e0d3a091dc0d81547d6e168be2b3492a&sdk_guid=32560d92-28f6-e067-7286-3f505a73e61a&client_origin=app%3A%2F%2Fstorefront.5b19b7150fb4f72d6831344b
```

the data is in JSON format.

You can extract the products with just `requests`, there's no need to use `BeautifulSoup`.

The following gets the data from *all* the pages!

```
import requests

url = "https://roeblingliquors.com/api/v1/products/search.json?additional_properties%5Btype%5D%5B%5D=Spirits&new_style=true&merchant_id=5b19b7150fb4f72d6831344b&limit=20&skip=0&api_key=e0d3a091dc0d81547d6e168be2b3492a&sdk_guid=32560d92-28f6-e067-7286-3f505a73e61a&client_origin=app%3A%2F%2Fstorefront.5b19b7150fb4f72d6831344b"

response = requests.get(url).json()

# This will left align the text by amount specified
fmt_string = "{:<70} {:<15} {:<10}"
print(fmt_string.format("Name", "Measure", "Price"))
print("-" * 100)

for data in response["data"]["products"]:
    for product in data["merchants"][0]["product_options"]:
        measure = (
            product["option_params"]["size"]["measure"]
            + " "
            + product["option_params"]["size"]["quantity"]
        )
        price = product["price"]

        print(fmt_string.format(data["name"], measure, price))
```

Output (truncated):

```
Name                                                                   Measure         Price     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plantation Rum Extra Old 20th Ann                                      ml 750          68.2      
Elijah Craig Barrel Proof Bourbon A121                                 ml 750          109.99    
Elijah Craig Small Batch Kentucky Straight Bourbon Whiskey 94 Proof    ml 750          37.38     
Tito's Vodka                                                           ml 50           2.53
```